# Stripe redirect issue with html5 url

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to redirect url which include hash in url `http://example.com/#/stripe` which is url of my angular app.

But on redirect time I am expecting

`http://example.com/#/stripe?client_secret=_secret&source=src`

Stripe is redirecting me to

`http://example.com/?client_secret=_secret&source=src#/stripe`

and my app is not getting values from url query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to redirect to a client-side routed URL in this case, so you'll probably want to send it to a server-side URL route that can handle processing the results in your system, and then redirect to whatever client-side routed URL you need to from there.

Comment: That i am going to do already. But I thought maybe there will be a solution. Thank you